# Find the limit of $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(1+e^x)-\ln2}{x}}$ without L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I have to find: $$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(1+e^x)-\ln2}{x}}$$
and I want to calculate it without using L'Hospital's rule. With L'Hospital's I know that it gives $1/2$.
Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try Taylor series?

Comment: Something that is missing from all the answers pointing out this is a derivative at $0$, i.e. you are computing $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$ for some function $f$: this shows **you shouldn't (even cannot) use L'Hopital for that.** Why? L'Hopital's rule amounts to saying "compute the derivatives of (i) $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ and (ii) $h(x) = x$ on a neighborhood of $0$, and **then** evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g'(x)}{h'(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{1} $.

Comment: But you want to compute... $f'(0)$ in the first place, so using L'Hopital is circular (on top of being overkill): it asks to compute $f'(x)$ in order to compute $f'(0)$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply differentiate $f(x)=\ln(e^x +1)$ at the point of abscissa $x=0$ and you’ll get the answer. in fact this is the definition of the derivative of $f$!!

Answer (score 25):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that does not rely on differential calculus, but rather uses the squeeze theorem and a set of inequalities that can be obtained with pre-calculus tools only.  To that end we proceed.

---

First note that in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm and exponential functions satisfy the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1\tag 1$$

and for $x<1$

$$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}\tag2$$

---

Next, note that $\log(1+e^x)-\log(2)=\log\left(\frac{e^x+1}2\right)$.  Hence, applying $(1)$, we can assert that

$$\frac{e^x -1}{e^x +1}\le \log(1+e^x)-\log(2)\le \frac{e^x-1}2\tag3$$

Then, applying $(2)$ to $(3)$ reveals

$$\frac{x}{e^x +1}\le \log(1+e^x)-\log(2)\le \frac{x}{2(1-x)}\tag4$$

Dividing $(4)$ by $x$, letting $x\to 0$, and applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+e^x)-\log(2)}{x}=\frac12}$$
>
> **Tools Used**:  The inequalities in $(1)$ and $(2)$ and the squeeze theorem.

Comment: can (1) or (2) be proved without differential calculus?

Comment: @daulomb Indeed.  I provided a link in the solution.  Did you not see it?  If not, [HERE IT IS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263).

Comment: I could not open the link but as I know the proof of Bernoulli's inequality also requires differentiation. Am I wrong? Neverthless your solution is very nice!

Comment: @daulomb Bernoulli's inequality can also be proved by induction; I agree teh solution is nice but is not simpler than others method

Comment: @gimusi: I see it thanks

Comment: Hi Mark ! Long time no speak.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi Cladue!!  How are you my friend?

Comment: @gimusi This answer is 'easier' than some others in the sense that it relies on more elementary methods.

Comment: @daulomb Bernoulli's inequality can be easily proven using induction.

Comment: @Mark Viola: yes it was so I did it. Thanks

Comment: @daulomb And with Bernoulli's Inequality and the limit definition of the exponential function, one can prove the inequalities in $(1)$ and $(2)$.  [HERE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) is the link one more time.

Comment: @Karl Thank you!  Much appreciative.  And happy holidays.

Comment: @MarkViola the fact that you use elementary methods does not mean that te derivation is simpler, anyway it's certainly instructive!

Comment: @gimusi As I said, if by "simpler" one means "using simpler methodologies, then it is certainly simpler.  If by "simpler," one means the most efficient, then it is not simpler.

Comment: +1, but you really don't need to bold entire paragraphs. It's very "loud," especially when you end one with an exclamation point.

Comment: @Thomasandrews First, happy holidays!  It's been a while.  Second, I appreciate the up vote.  And third, I will definitely tone down things going forward.  -Mark

Answer (score 7):

Let $y = e^x$

$$L = \lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(1+e^x)-\ln2}{x}} = \lim_{y\to1}{\frac{\ln(1+y)-\ln2}{\ln y}}$$

Let $z = y -1$

$$L =  \lim_{z\to0}{\frac{\ln(z + 2)-\ln2}{\ln(z+1)}} = \dfrac12\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\ln(z/2 + 1)}{z/2}\dfrac{z}{\ln(z+1)}= \dfrac12$$

Comment: yes I've seen also that now :) +1 for similar solution

Answer (score 5):

This is just the derivative of $\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}2\right)$ at $0$, which is indeed $\frac12$.

Comment: Why the extra factor $2$? It is simpler to see it as the derivative of $\ln(1+e^x)$, without the additional division by $2$ (which, given it's inside the logarithm, is an additive term anyway).

Comment: @ClementC. Thats because in order to check that it was indeed an indeterminate form, the first thing I did was the transformation $\ln(e^x+1)-\ln2=\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}2\right)$. But, yes, there is no need no do that.

Answer (score 4):

That's just the derivative of $\ln\left(e^x+1\right)$ at $0$.

If you don't see it, by Taylor's series:

$${\frac{\ln(1+e^x)-\ln2}{x}}={\frac{\ln(2+x+o(x))-\ln2}{x}}=\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x))}{x}=\frac{\frac{x}{2}+o(x)}{x}=\frac12+o(1)\to\frac12$$

Answer (score 4):

Solution by **standard limits**:

set $$1+e^x=2+y \quad y\to 0\implies e^x=1+y \implies x= \ln (1+y)$$

thus

$${\frac{\ln(1+e^x)-\ln2}{x}}=\frac{\ln (2+y)-\ln 2}{\ln(1+y)}=\frac{\ln (1+\frac{y}{2})}{\ln(1+y)}=\frac{\ln (1+\frac{y}{2})}{\frac y2}\frac{y}{\ln (1+y)}\frac12\to 1\cdot 1\cdot \frac12=\frac12$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes of course $y\to0$ too!

Comment: [Somebody already posted this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2575860/450905).

Comment: @123 I've seen it now! Anyway it's slightly different and I think you have to add an $\frac12$ term at the end!

Answer (score 3):

There's an amusing way to prove, if the limit exists, it must be $1/2.$ Obviously, not a complete answer, since it doesn't prove the limit exists.)

Letting $f(x)=\log(1+e^x)$ then we have $f(x)=\log(1+e^{x})=\log(e^x)+\log(1+e^{-x})=x+f(-x)$ and thus $f(x)-f(-x)=x.$

So if $L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ then $$1=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}+\frac{f(-x)-f(0)}{-x}\right]=2L$$

And thus we get $L=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

A more complete answer uses that we know that:

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y}=1.$$

Then we can write:

$$\frac{\log(1+e^x)-\log2}{x}=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{e^x-1}{2}\right)}{\frac{e^x-1}{2}}\cdot \frac{\frac{e^x-1}{2}}{x}$$

Letting $y=\frac{e^x-1}{2}$, we get that $y\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ and $x=\log(1+2y)$ so we get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+e^x)-\log2}{x}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y}\cdot \frac{2y}{\log(2y+1)}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=1\cdot 1\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

This is really just a long way of proving the chain rule for the derivative of $\log(e^x+1).$

---

[Complete answer updated to use the neat trick of gimusi at the end, rather than using $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\to 1$ as well.]

Comment: Nice the second is similar to mine by standard limits, +1 for the first!

Comment: I had a slightly more complicated answer for the complete answer, but I added a simplication based roughly on your answer. I was still using $y=\frac{e^x-1}{2}$ all along, I just assumed $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\to 1$ also. So I updated with a rough assist from your answer. Edited to reflect your help.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by one of the replies on the question, you can notice that $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {ln(1+e^x)-ln2}{x} $$ is written in the format of one of the theoretical definition of derivative at point x : 
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{x} $$
Therefore, x can be evaluated to 0 and $ f(x) = ln(1+e^x)$ 
Using this function, calculate its derivative which is $$ f'(x) = \frac {1}{1+e^x} (e^x) $$ Then you plug $ x=0 $ to get the answer $$ f'(1) = \frac{e^0}{1+e^0} = \frac{1}{2} $$